# Does the Unity AWS Sdk support standalone or only mobile?

Tags: amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine

I am looking for a Backend-as-a-Service provider for my standalone game. The AWS Unity Sdk looks very interesting, but it is labeled as "AWS Mobile Sdk." Does this mean that only mobile platforms are supported, or am I missing something?

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Standalone is supported by AWSSDK.
If you search Unity and AWS, most of the information is concerning with the mobile SDK, part of the function like CognitoID is available, but there is special consideration supporting Unity as you can only import DLLs to acess AWSSDK rather than the NugetForUnity. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/latest/developer-guide/unity-special.html) is the official document guiding you downloading the DLLs.
And [here](https://github.com/RealBrandonChen/AWSS3_UnityDemo) is my repository which is a demo of Unity directory uploading implemented with AWSS3 bucket.
Thank you for your question.